# Problems executing umount in shell script but not manually

Tags: mount, scripts, unmount, azure

I have been creating a shell script to restore our azure fileshares when needed. Previously we executed these tasks manually and we did not have problems with that but we decided to automate those.

With that said, the script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash

dest_folder=$1
environment=$2

for df in $dest_folder*
do
  sudo umount $df/ && \
  while  [ "$(mountpoint $df/)" != "$df/ is not a mountpoint" ]; 
    do echo "Executing umount: $(mountpoint $df/)"
    sleep 1
  done && echo "Umount executed"
done

sudo rm -r $dest_folder*

mkdir -p /path/data/fileshare

### replace with command to mount fileshare ###
mount -a

mkdir -p /path/data/globalconfig

### replace with command to mount fileshare ###
mount -a
```

The current problem is that sometimes when this script is executed it does the umount correctly but sometimes it gets stuck mounting the fileshare without any logical reason and resulting in **echo "... is not a mountpoint"**. I do no have any clue of what could be going on in this situation

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Could you explain what's the purpose of the `while` loop?

Comment: Thanks! Since those are virtual machines created from a defined image, could exist the possibility that those folders were mounted before and in some cases when I execute **sudo umount /path/to/mount/** it gets applied to the current one but immediately It changes to an older mount. So to make sure that it is totally unmounted I created the script in that way

Comment: Found somtehing... the /etc/fstab is completly messy since I have been "automating" this mounting and tested it with several fileshares, so, this file has some additional records and gets mounted several times